# Setting ShowCompleted for google tasks

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-tasks-api

How would I set the ShowCompleted flag in google tasks for DotNet?
I've searched the samples with no luck.

[tasks.get](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/get)

```
Task task = service.Tasks.Get("@default", "taskID").Fetch();
Console.WriteLine(task.Title);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Remember to post the code you have tried as well as showing any research you have done by listing any links you have already checked.   I have tried to improve your question giving you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using tasks.get you can just check `task.Completed`

```
var task = service.Tasks.Get("@default", "taskID").Fetch();
Console.WriteLine(task.Completed);
```

Comment: I'm using  Service.Tasks.List(list.Id).ShowCompleted = true;
                var tasks = await Service.Tasks.List(list.Id).ExecuteAsync();